# Whenever Capistrano - Cron file Updated, but not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, capistrano, whenever

I'm trying to setup cron jobs on my rails server with Whenever and Capistrano.

schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
  p "SUCCESS in every MINUTE"
  runner "myObject.HELLO()"
end
```

from local directory `$whenever --update`

```
"SUCCESS in every MINUTE"
[write] crontab file updated
You have new mail in /var/mail/username
```

CapFile

```
 require 'whenever/capistrano'
```

deploy.rb

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
set :whenever_identifier, -> {"#{fetch(:appName)}_#{fetch(:production)}"}
```

Does this work? If not what should I change and how do I test it?

Capistrano 3

Comment: What makes you think it isn't running? What does `myObject.HELLO()` do? Be aware that `p` will only print something for the `cron` user, it won't print anything that you can read unless you direct the output to a file.

Comment: @eirikir How do I read the `p` logs from cron?

Comment: They're lost to the unix ether unless you output them somewhere: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/84304